# Can you use the activeElement property to see if an element with a specific class name has focus?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get the Boolean `true` if elements with a certain class name are focused on. But it seems Document.activeElement only works with either ID or Tag name, which wont help since they're elements of the same type. Heres the situation:

```js
var test2 = document.getElementsByClassName('test2')
var test3 = document.getElementsByClassName('test3')

test3[1].focus()

isFocused2 = (document.activeElement === test2)
isFocused3 = (document.activeElement === test3)

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = isFocused3
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test2">
<input type="text" class="test3">
<input type="text" class="test2">
<input type="text" class="test3">

<div id="test"></div>
```

@Michael It works ONLY if the `focus ()` is set to the input as you'll see below, but clicking on the input doesn't seem to make it active hence making the isFocused variable stay on false (my mistake in giving you the idea that i wanted to use that method to focus instead of clicking)

```js
const prev = document.getElementsByClassName('prev');
const curr = document.getElementsByClassName('curr');

// curr[1].focus()

var isFocused1 = document.activeElement.classList.contains("prev");
var isFocused2 = document.activeElement.classList.contains("curr");


function fx2 () {
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += isFocused1 + ' ' + isFocused2 + ' '
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
   <td><input type="text" name="" class="prev" onclick="fx2()"></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="" class="curr" onclick="fx2()"></td>
   <td><p class="Mtr-result"></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td><input type="text" name="" class="prev" onclick="fx2()"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="" class="curr" onclick="fx2()"></td>
<td><p class="Mtr-result"></p></td>
    </tr>


<div  id="test"></div>
```

as you can see the focus method has been commented out, and the onclick event attribute on the input calls the `fx2()` function that changes the innerHTML value of the 'test' div to the value of isFocused 1 and 2, which both show false.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a list, that is why your comparison is failing.

Comment: You simply want `document.activeElement.classList.contains("test2")`

Comment: check new code please

Comment: You don't need `=== test2` (and the `test2` declaration) any longer. Just `var isFocused2 = document.activeElement.classList.contains("test2");`

Comment: @shuheim It should just be:  `isFocused2 = document.activeElement.classList.contains("test2")`

Comment: @Bergi sorry, was typing in parallel xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bergi and Zachiah pointed out in the comments, all you need to do is use `document.activeElement.classList.contains("test2")` to check if the focused element has the `test2` class.

[`Element.classList.contains(class)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a method that you can call on any element, including `document.activeElement`. If the element you're calling it contains the class passed to the method, then it will return `true`, otherwise it will return `false`.

```js
var test2 = document.getElementsByClassName('test2')
var test3 = document.getElementsByClassName('test3')

var isFocused2;
var isFocused3;

function fx() {
  isFocused2 = document.activeElement.classList.contains("test2")
  isFocused3 = document.activeElement.classList.contains("test3")

  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = isFocused2 + ' ' + isFocused3;
}

window.addEventListener('focusin', fx);
window.addEventListener('focusout', fx);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test2">
<input type="text" class="test3">
<input type="text" class="test2">
<input type="text" class="test3">

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I do appreciate the code, but it seems it only shows ```true``` if the focus method is added, please refer to the code above in the question.

Comment: @shuheim Always happy to help! If you want `isFocused2` and `isFocused3` to update whenever the focus on the page changes, then create an event handler for the `focusin` event on `window`, then update the variables from there. See my updated code.

Comment: Agreed that adding multiple handlers on every input seems to go against the DRY principle, however due to lack of other solutions i used it to solve a problem i was having with letting the arrow keys navigate input fields, adding ```onclick``` to ALL inputs. If you got a more efficient way i could message you the code?

Comment: Also, did you put the isFocused2 and 3 IN the function after i commented about the focus method? i completely missed that.

Comment: @shuheim Regarding `isFocused2` and `isFocused3`, I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you ask that, but you can read the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76349723/revisions) of my answer. Regarding the `onclick` event handlers, I'd be happy to help, however, the comment section is not the best place to do it. If you'd like you can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or even just email me the code and any questions you have (see my user profile for my email). You might also want to google/research event propagation and event bubbling in JS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76360598/13713975 ( the new question )

Answer (score 1):

`document.activeElement` works fine :

```js
const test3 = document.querySelector('.test3');

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => {
  el.onfocus = state;
  el.onblur = state;
  function state() {
    document.getElementById('active-focus-class').innerHTML = document.activeElement.getAttribute('class');
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = document.activeElement === test3;
  }
})

test3.focus();
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test1">
<input type="text" class="test2">
<input type="text" class="test3">
<input type="text" class="test4">

<p>.test3 is focused: <b id="test"></b>
<p>activeElement className: <b id="active-focus-class"></b>
```

Comment: If the user clicks out of the input box, the focus doesn't update to reflect that.

Comment: Added a function call to the `onblur` event as well.

Comment: I'd guess this approach isn't as effective (or at least, not as neat) as adding a two event handlers on `window` and letting the events bubble up. Adding two event handlers for every input box on the page isn't the best way.

Comment: Friend, if you can prove your point that my code is inefficient, I'll buy you a beer. So far, on the pledge of volunteerism, I have answered your question.

Comment: learned about blur method, thx, the active focus class part was interesting, i did something similar but with a combo of ```if else``` and ```classlist.contain```.

Comment: There's no need to use `isSameNode`. Just compare directly.

Comment: @Unmitigated , Yes you're right. Old habit.